# How to fire a command after clicking somewhere else?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So, I have a custom control, *CusConA*, that works basically like a textbox - you type amount of money that you need, and I have a button below, whom by getting clicked saves that amount(from CusConA) somewhere, and that is working fine.

But I want to try the same functionality basically by clicking anywhere on that page (something like OnBlur in asp.net), or to be precise, when my CusConA is not in focus anymore.

By doing what is shown with the --> in code, I achieved sort of a solution, this way when pressing anywhere, even if I never even tried to write an amount, the command is being executed.

So, to try to circle my question, I need this command to execute only after typing some amount, and clicking somewhere alse after. How can I do that?

```
<Frame
            Margin="55,0"
            Padding="0"
            BorderColor="Blue"
            CornerRadius="30">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label
                    Margin="10"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="RSD"
                    TextColor="Some text"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                <customControls:CusConA
                    Margin="0,0,15,0"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    Placeholder="0,00"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                    Text="Some text"
                    TextColor="Black" >
-->                  <customControls:CusConA.Behaviors>
                        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior  EventName="Unfocused" Command="{Binding DoSomething}" ></xct:EventToCommandBehavior>
                    </customControls:CusConA.Behaviors>
                </customControls:CusConA>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change DoSomething to check whether the amount has been typed? Might involve adding a boolean property to your control:

```
bool CanExecute { get; set; }
```

Then have "amount" bound to a property whose setter sets `CanExecute = true;` or `CanExecute = false;`, depending on whether an amount has been typed. Something like:

```
string Amount
{
    ...
    set {
        _amount = value;
        myControl.CanExecute = value.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Then change `DoSomething` body to

```
if (this.CanExecute) { ... }
```

---

Alternatively, other techniques can be used to have a change to `Amount` trigger a change to a property on `myControl`.

The essential points are:

1. Adding `CanExecute` property, so control can be told when it is valid to execute that command.
2. Using some technique to bind or trigger `myControl.CanExecute` change, from elsewhere.

Comment: That is basically what we have done! Created a Command that checks if there is anything typed, and it is working!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `EventToCommandBehavior` to achieve this function.

There is an example of an `EventToCommandBehavior` in the Xamarin.Forms samples (see [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs)).

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <focusapp:MyViewModel></focusapp:MyViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <Entry>
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior 
        EventName="Unfocused" 
        Command="{Binding EntryUnfocused}" />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

</StackLayout>
```

And define `EntryUnfocused` in your viewmodel.cs (e.g. `MyViewModel`) just as follows:

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ICommand EntryUnfocused { get; protected set; }

    public MyViewModel() {

        EntryUnfocused = new Command(CompletedCommandExecutedAsync);
    }

    private void CompletedCommandExecutedAsync(object param)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------------> come here....");
    }
}
```